# How to Stop TextMeshPro Truncate from Removing Next Line? Unity 2020.3.1f1

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

In updating from Unity 2019 to 2020, it appears the TextMeshPro (TMP_Text) is behaving differently. The code for TMP stayed the same upon updating Unity, so I presume Unity itself must be doing something differently. Nevertheless, I also updated the TMP package and it did not resolve the issue.

**The Issue:**
I have two lines of text in one text box. I want the overflow to be truncated, but to keep the second line in existence. Example Input:

```
This is the really long text on the first line that I want cut but
still have this line show.
```

In short, I want it to read as follows when using the "truncate" option like it used to work before

```
This is the really long text
still have this line show.
```

Instead, the second line disappears and it acts as if I have only that first line (centered vertically).

```
This is the really long text
```

So how do I get this functionality back? Is it possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the Inspector configuration of your TextMeshPro component, and its bounds as visualized in the scene view?

Comment: Done...........

Comment: What happens if you make your box taller?

Comment: One line dead center